# comes to think of it?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions

Which of the expressions, "come to think of it" or "comes to think of it", grammatically correct? Or are they grammatical at all?

If it is a short form of,

> When one comes to think of it, I would rather have a cat.

It should be

> Comes to think of it, I would rather have a cat.

But it seems that it is more often used as

> Come to think of it, I would rather have a cat.

Which one is correct?

Grammatically, it neither seems to be a normal sentence. Are there more expressions with similar structure (verb phrase that is not an imperative).

Comment: If it's short for anything, it's actually "When I come to think of it", not "one".

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross Cool. Is there a situation where "When one comes to think of it" could be truncated, and is valid?

Comment: One could certainly use it if one were to speak in an absurdly formal fashion. But you couldn't use "Comes to think of it", because it's a fixed phrase which should be "Come to think..." You would have to use the full "When one..."

Comment: You wouldn't mix pronouns by saying: "When **one** comes to think of it, **I** would rather have a cat." You would use either "I" or "one" both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression *[come to think of it](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come?q=come%20to%20think%20of%20it#come__56)* actually functions as a phrase

> **come to think of it**
>
> on reflection (said when an idea or point occurs to one while one is speaking):
> *come to think of it, that was very daring of you*

and therefore "*Come to think of it, I would rather have a cat.*" is the correct choice of sentence.

Comment: As usual, it's a truncated clause. St.JotC got it in one: _When I come to think about it_ is indeed the fixed clause that becomes a fixed phrase by deletion of the _when_ and the _I_ subject.